# Why does type.convert not convert large "integers" that are stored as numeric to integer?

Tags: r

```
class(type.convert(as.numeric(1e3)))
# [1] "integer"
class(type.convert(as.numeric(1e4)))
# [1] "integer"
class(type.convert(as.numeric(1e5)))
# [1] "numeric"
class(type.convert(as.numeric(1e6)))
# [1] "numeric"
```

Why are the larger ones not converted to integers? There is still a lot to go to:

```
.Machine$integer.max
# [1] 2147483647
```

Maybe the answer can be found in the C source of `typeconvert` on [GitHub](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/library/utils/src/io.c)?
Unfortunately I am quite unfamiliar with C.

Comment: What version of R are you running? When I run any of those commands I get an error for type.convert: `the first argument must be of mode character`.

Comment: @mickey R version 3.5.1

Comment: Incredibly peculiar. If you try `class(type.convert(as.numeric(100001)))` you get `integer`, while with `class(type.convert(as.numeric(100000)))` you get `numeric`.

Comment: Maybe it's the way R uses scientific notation? `100000` prints to `1e+05`

Comment: BTW, it's nice how `type.convert` is described in the comments of the source code: `This is a horrible hack which is used in read.table to take a
   character variable, if possible to convert it...`. Lol.

Comment: To add to @mickey's point, my input is that this behaviour disappears after `options(scipen=999)` so that it indeed is related to scientific notation.

Comment: `i=10000;
while( class(type.convert(as.numeric(i))) == "integer" ) {
    i = i + 1
};
print(i)`  .... 1e+05 is the first number to not fullfill integer conversion.

Comment: the next one `2e+05` and so on....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, this is less strange than it appears. Let's give a look to the source code of `utils:::type.convert.default`:

```
function (x, na.strings = "NA", as.is = FALSE, dec = ".", numerals = c("allow.loss", 
    "warn.loss", "no.loss"), ...) 
{
    if (is.array(x)) 
        storage.mode(x) <- "character"
    else x <- as.character(x)
    .External2(C_typeconvert, x, na.strings, as.is, dec, match.arg(numerals))
}
```

The important part is `x <- as.character(x)`: no matter what the input is, it gets coerced to a character before trying to convert its type (this is quite peculiar, since a `numeric` or `integer` vector might be returned as is, without further processing in my opinion). How this is done, it depends on the nature and value of `x`. For instance:

```
#numeric value
as.character(100000)
#[1] "1e+05"
#integer value
as.character(100000L)
#[1] "100000"
```

When it tries to `type.convert`, `"100000"` is a suitable integer string, while `"1e+05"` is not, and this explain the different behaviour. Consider that `as.character` depends also on the `scipen` option. If set sufficiently high, the `as.character` doesn't produce a scientific notation, but a number which may be considered integer by `type.convert`.

```
options(scipen=999)
options("scipen")
as.character(100000)
#[1] "100000"
```

Comment: So adding `options(scipen=999)` at the beginning and `options(scipen=0)` at the end should be safe? Maybe this issue should be resolved by R core?

Comment: I guess that it's actually not an issue, since the argument of `type.convert` is supposed to be a `character` vector. Consider that `type.convert` is used mostly for `read.table` and is not intended to convert something that is not to be converted. I don't think the R core team will be much willing to change this stuff and maybe the safest thing you should do is to avoid to pass to `type.convert` something that is not `character`.

Comment: It is not mentioned in the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/type.convert.html). In my opinion `type.convert` could be nice automatic type converter, and in this particular case integer value is preferred, as it uses less memory.

Comment: I agree with you, but the way it's written gives the idea that its only purpose is to be used by `read.table`. In the doc there are also examples of conversion between numeric and integer; but, as it is now, it's totally unreliable.